# maven-jaxb2-plugin isn't generating any output

Tags: maven, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-basics

I'm new to Maven, and am trying to use it to generate the Java classes from my XSD.

My xsd file is in src/main/resources/xsd

In dependencies I have this, but I don't think I need it as I'm using Java 1.6

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

In the build section I have

```
    <build>
     <pluginManagement>
     ..
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.6</source>
               <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     ..
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeSchemas>
                                <includeSchema>**/test.xsd</includeSchema>
                            </includeSchemas>

                            <generatePackage>com.myproject.adapter.generated</generatePackage>
                            <bindingDirectory>src/main/binding</bindingDirectory>
                            <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

But, when I run it, I get nothing.
I've run mvn compile and generate-sources, with the -e and -X flags to have a look at the output, but it seems the target isn't getting invoked. 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first off you should always specify which version of a dependency or plugin you are using

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.8.0</version>
```

then you have to supply the following entries inside an execution

```
<schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
<schemaIncludes>
  <include>test.xsd</include>
</schemaIncludes>
```

Here is a complete definition, I have included the jaxb2-basics plugin as you almost always want what it does.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.8.0</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>jaxb-test</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>generate</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
      <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
      <schemaIncludes>
        <include>test.xsd</include>
      </schemaIncludes>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
  <extension>true</extension>
  <args>
    <arg>-XtoString</arg>
    <arg>-Xequals</arg>
    <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
    <arg>-Xcopyable</arg>
    <arg>-Xmergeable</arg>
  </args>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
      <version>0.6.0</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a big help, however now it appears to be ignoring whatever I've put in the <schemaDirectory> tag. The log is now showing   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.7.1:g
enerate (default-cli) on project cciAdapter-core: Execution default-cli of goal
org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.7.1:generate failed: basedir I:\dev\
adapter\cciAdapter-core\src\main\resources does not exist -> [Help 1], so it's still using the defaults.

Comment: @Scott you have to specify the correct version of the plugin, `0.7.1` is an old version see my example for the latest version. also make sure your directory path is correct, it should be relative to your `pom.xml` file.

Comment: Thanks Jarrod. I reverted back to 0.7.1 as I was following another blog post. I tried jixb today, and think it wasn't finding it as it's a multi module project. Jixb has a <multi-module>true</multi-module> tag, but I haven't found something like this for jaxb. I  got closer to success when I moved this into one of the modules.